# Azure DevOps branch policy path filter to detect changes in the project root folder

Tags: azure-devops

I have a path structure like /a/b.

I want to enforce branch policies based on which files have changed as follows:

Policy 1. When a file has changed in the root folder or folder a.

Policy 2. When no files have changed in the root folder or folder a.

How can I do this with path filters?

(I tried "./*;./a/*" and "./*.*;./a/*.*" but it seems like the wildcards match files at any level. ie. It would apply even if there was a file change in folder b.)

Comment: Why don't you try only `/a/*` for policy 1?